# install package (library) for crosscompiler

Tags: cmake, linker, cross-compiling, libraries

I would like to

- use the crosscompiler `gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu` to build a binary
- **link a precompiled library** (e.g. `libxml2.so`/`libxml2.a`) to that binary
- use **cmake**

I thought of the following way to achieve the above:

1. creating a **sysroot** folder (is this the correct term?)
2. downloading the library by `apt-get download libxml2-dev:arm64`
3. "installing" the package into the **sysroot** folder by `dpkg-deb -x libxml2_*_arm64.deb ./sysroot/`
4. declaring the **sysroot** folder in `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH`
5. using `find_package()` in cmake to locate the library in **sysroot**

**Question:** Is the way above a good one? Is there a better one? I am surely not the first one facing that problem, therefore I think there might be a better way.